# I'm trying to get ansible output formatted like item1 - item2 instead of two separate lists of items

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible, json-query

I have a functioning ansible script that connects to AWS and prints out tags from instances in a specified state.

The problem I'm having is the print out is two separate lists e.g.

What I get is:

```
name1
name2
name3

description1
description2
description3
```

What I would like is:

```
name1 - description1
name2 - description2
name3 - description3
```

I've tried pushing this all into a dictionary, but got lost in the attempt. There must be an easier way.

Here's my code:

```
 - name: print stopped systems
   hosts: all
   become: false
   tasks:

   - name: Gather ec2_metadata_facts (use -vv to show all)
     action: ec2_metadata_facts

   - name: pull instance info with ec2_instance_info
     ec2_instance_info:
       region: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_DEFAULT_REGION') }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
       filters:
         instance-state-name: [ "shutting-down", "stopping", "stopped" ]
     register: ec2_info

   - name: print Instance Info
     debug:
       msg:
         - "{{ ec2_info | json_query(name_tag) }}"
         - "{{ ec2_info | json_query(description_tag) }}"
     vars:
       name_tag: "instances[*].tags.Name"
       description_tag: "instances[*].tags.Description"
```

The output of the debug statement looks like this:

```
TASK [print Instance Info] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [tools-server-01] => 
  msg:
  - - server-01
    - server-02
  - - Description for server one
    - Description for server two
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `zip` filter? eg. `[a, b, c] | zip([1, 2, 3])` will give `[[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rickkwa

I've got this mostly working.
here's my current code

```
 - name: Print stopped systems
   hosts: all
   become: false
   tasks:

   - name: Gather ec2_metadata_facts (use -vv to show all)
     action: ec2_metadata_facts

   - name: pull instance info with ec2_instance_info
     ec2_instance_info:
       region: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_DEFAULT_REGION') }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
       filters:
         instance-state-name: [ "shutting-down", "stopping", "stopped" ]
     register: ec2_info

   - name: Create Name list
     no_log: true
     set_fact: 
       name_l: "{{ec2_info | json_query(name_tag)}}"
     vars:
       name_tag: "instances[*].tags.Name"

   - name: Create Description list
     no_log: true
     set_fact: 
       desc_l: "{{ ec2_info | json_query(description_tag) }}"
     vars:
       description_tag: "instances[*].tags.Description"

   - name: print together
     debug:
       msg: "{{item.0}} --- {{item.1}}"
     loop: "{{ name_l|zip(desc_l)|list}}"
```

Unfortunately, the last debug statement includes some 'garbage" I'd like to remove...anyone have a suggestion to get rid of the stuff following the "u"s?

here's the output :'

```
TASK [print together] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dev-bsd-01] => (item=[u'server-01', u'server one description']) => 
  msg: server-01 --- server one description
ok: [dev-bsd-01] => (item=[u'server-02', u'server two description']) => 
  msg: server-02 --- server two description
```